# Mostrar datos de bucle coincidentes de forma seguida

Tags: php, array, bucles

Quiero mostrar en un bucle las coincidencias seguidas. En el ejemplo que pongo las coincidencias salen mezcladas con el resto de resultados dando esto:

```
131411578
```

La idea sería que primero saliesen todos los 1 o datos que coincidan con la condición del `if`, *lo de poner números es solo un ejemplo*.

Pensé que saldrían primero las coincidencias, pero salen en función del orden del `array`, entonces quiero saber como hacer esto en el bucle y que salga **1111** primero y después los demás datos conservando su orden.

```
111134578
```

Sé que podría hacerse con otro bucle que reuniese estos datos, pero quiero saber cómo hacerlo con un solo bucle.

```
<? 
  $array=array("1","3","1","4","1","1","5","7","8");
  foreach($array as $ar){
    if($ar=="1"){
      print "".$ar."";
    } else {
      print "".$ar."";
    }
  }
?>
```

Muchas gracias a todos, un saludo.

Comment: Hola Jean, el problema con tu código, es que si hay coincidencia -> **print "".$ar."";** y si no hay coincidencia... -> **print "".$ar."";**... deberías modificar algo, por ejemplo que el **else** imprima "-".

Comment: @jean si la respuesta no es lo que buscas, por favor edita tu pregunta o deja un comentario en la respuesta y así podemos explorar otras opciones.

Answer (score 0):

**Actualizo mi respuesta basándome en el comentario del OP**.

Podrías crear una variable vacía para concatenar los números o el texto al principio o al final de la misma, dependiendo si coincide o no con el parámetro a comparar en el `if`.

```
<?php
    $array = array("1","9","1","6","1","1","2","7","3");
    //Declarar una variable vacía
    $salida = '';
    foreach($array as $ar){
        if($ar == "1"){
            //Si coincide se concatena al inicio
            $salida = $ar.$salida; 
        } else {
            //En caso contrario, se concatena al final
            $salida = $salida.$ar;
        }
    }
    //Finalmente se imprime la variable 
    echo $salida;
    
    //Un ejemplo con texto
    $letras = array("a","e","a","f","a","a","b","d","c");
    $salida = '';
    foreach($letras as $letra){
        if($letra == "a"){
            $salida = $letra.$salida; 
        } else {
            $salida = $salida.$letra;
        }
    }
    echo($salida);
?>
```

Las respectivas salidas serían estas:

```
111196273
aaaaefbdc
```

*Respuesta inicial no aprobada por el OP*:

Usando los métodos `sort()` o `asort()` de `php` puedes ordernar un `array` de manera ascendente de acuerdo al valor de cada elemento.

```
<?php
  $array=array("1","3","1","4","1","1","5","7","8");
  asort($array);
  foreach ($array as $ar) {
    echo $ar;
  }
?>
```

El resultado sería el siguiente:

```
111134578
```

Para consultar otros métodos de ordenamiento de `php`, puedes visitar [este enlace de w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_arrays_sort.asp) o [este enlace de php](https://www.php.net/manual/en/array.sorting.php).

Comment: Eso fue lo que yo publiqué, pero me instaron a eliminar la publicación ya que no es lo que el OP solicitaba :-(

Comment: @rpaillao no puedo creer que te hicieran eliminar tu respuesta!... A grandes rasgos es lo que se logra interpretar de la pregunta. Si la respuesta no es correcta el OP siempre puede editar su pregunta o dejar comentarios al respecto y de esa manera se le pueden ofrecer otras alternativas. Últimamente he notado que hay usuarios que votan negativamente a las respuestas sin dejar comentarios y sin dejar siquiera la respuesta que consideran apropiada. Queda cierta incertidumbre con esos comportamientos.

Comment: Es q lo dispuesto no tiene nada que ver con lo q yo puse, el ordenamiento en base a sort no tiene nada q ver con lo q pregunté, dado q me refiero a cualquier tipo de dato que salga en el orde indicado porque se da la coincidencia o la condición con if, no en base a ningún tipo de ordenamiento, la idea es q todas las coincidencias salgan primero y luego las demás

Comment: Edité la respuesta inicial. Espero haber captado la idea esta vez. De no ser así, puedes dejar un nuevo comentario.